# Error passing variable between Activity 

Tags: android

this is my Manual.java file:

```
public class Manual extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button create;
    TextView gotAnswer, NoAnsV;
    EditText NoQues, NoAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manualask);     
        NoQues = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.NoQues);
        NoAnswer = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.NoAnsw);
        create = (Button) findViewById (R.id.create);
        create.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        switch (v.getId()){     
        case R.id.create:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Manual.this, MCQSample.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            Integer Number = Integer.parseInt(NoQues.getText().toString());         
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;

    }
    }
}
```

Then the MCQSample.java:

```
public class MCQSample extends Activity{

    TextView title;
    String gotBread;
    int value;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mcqsample); 
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int value = b.getInt("key", 0);
        title.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Then the mcqsample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/abc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Both classes I have already added in the AndroidManifest.

When I click the create button on the Manual.java it always crashes. What wrong with my classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set the number to the bundle, you should call [`Bundle#putInt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(NoQues.getText().toString());         
b.putInt("key", number);
intent.putExtras(b);
```

The second problem (which causes the crash) is, that you should set text, not int:

```
title.setText("" + value);
```

Otherwise it looks for a string with the id = value, and such id doesn't exist (see [`TextView#setText(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)).

Comment: Oh tks a yottabyte. I've stucked this part for the whole day! ~~. I've just learn Android

Comment: btw the last question, how can we transfer the array instead of int? Is the way same?

Comment: Pretty much, take a look at putIntArray: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putIntArray%28java.lang.String,%20int%5B%5D%29

Answer (score 0):

**Manual**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Manual.this, MCQSample.class);
intent.putExtras("val",NoQues.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

**MCQSample**

```
int value= Integer.parseInt( getIntent().getExtras().getString("val") );
```